# While Loop String check

Tags: java

I cant get out of this loop when i enter M or F

```
while(!optionGender.equals("M") || !optionGender.equals("F")){
            System.out.println("Not an option, please try again");
            optionGender = promptUser.nextLine();
            optionGender = optionGender.toUpperCase();

        }
```

Comment: `||` should be `&&`

Comment: still not working

Comment: The conditions inside while are opposite to each other, So no matter what input you give one condition will be set to true. As mentioned in the above comment by @4castle || should be replaced by &&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your condition `||` by `&&`,

```
while(!optionGender.equals("M") && !optionGender.equals("F")){
                System.out.println("Not an option, please try again");
                optionGender = promptUser.nextLine();
                optionGender = optionGender.toUpperCase();
   }
```

Comment: @DanielChen are you using `m` or `f` instead of `M` or `F`.

Comment: @DanielChen better to use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`. It will check for `M` as well as `m`.